# Copy a list that's created by alphabetizing information and them matching the information

Tags: excel, copy, lookup

I have a list of names

```
A         B
```

| Client | Opposing |

| Josh   | Max      |
| Greg   | Peter    |

which is then alphabetized in the next column (C).

A------------ B  -------- C ----------           D

Client | Opposing    |  Auto Alpha |   Opposing

Josh   | Max      -------  --    Greg

Greg   | Peter     --------     Josh

and what I want is for the opposing (D) to automatically populate with the matching name from the opposing side (B) for the alphabetized column (c). currently we're using a single cell: josh/max, but it doesn't work well and it's a pita to search. I need to have the opposing column (D) fill in with the name from column (B) which is beside the matching name in (A) once sorted alphabetically in (C).

So in my magic spreadsheet the matching names would automatically populate to show the following

A    -------------     B ----------------  C---------------------- D

Client |----- Opposing  |  -----  Auto Alpha  | ------ Opposing

Josh   |--------- Max ----------------- |Greg ----------Peter

Greg   | --------Peter   --------------- |Josh -------------          Max

I'm hoping I'm making sense...

if anyone knows how i can have it pull that information and make it work i'd really appreciate it!

I tried making index/match formulas but i'm not really good at this stuff and it didnt work.

ugh i used the table button and now it looks like crap when i actually post my question forgive all my dashes, I'm trying to make it look like a table... i'm just a guy who doesn't know what he's doing but knows more than the rest of my office. :(

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,FALSE)`

Comment: Scott, i love you. You have no idea how much time i've put into this and you fixed it so fast. You're amazing!

Comment: It won't let me edit my previous comment, not sure why...

I have a question though. i'm also trying to make a reverse alphabetized list using the opposing alphabetized, basically reversing columns c and d, but when i do it doesn't work. i get a #N/A. I change it to be using e2 (the opposing alphabetized list column) and change it to search column 1 (to pull the matching name from A) in the col_index_number but it doesn't work. if i go to show calculation steps it shows the following: 

=VLOOKUP("peter",A:B,1,FALSE)

But the final conclusion is a #N/A

any idea?

Comment: sorted it out! used xlookup and it was able to do what i wanted. from what i understand vlookup can only go left to right, and xlookup can go both.